# node-gyp rebuild issue when installing dependencies for wallet

Tags: wallet, hardware-wallet

I am attempting to build wallet from source but following the instructions in the README. My motivation is I'm interested in a hardware wallet concept / wallet projects in general.

Running OS X 10.12.6 and I installed all prereqs listed in the wallet repo.

`$ git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet`

`$ cd wallet`

`$ git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/iri`

`$ cd iri`

Following `iri` doc:

`$ mvn clean compile`

`$ mvn package`

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
[ERROR] ... etc etc
```

`$ mvn package -DskipTests=true`

I confirmed that there are `jar`s built in `wallet/iri/target`

`$ cd ..`

Follow wallet docs:

`$ npm install`

`ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/Users/casey/miniconda3/bin/python" is v3.6.3, which is not supported by gyp.`

`$ npm install --python=python2.7`

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/casey/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/casey/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node" "/Users/casey/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/casey/Dev/iota/wallet/node_modules/ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-linux@1.1.0 (node_modules/7zip-bin-linux):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-linux@1.1.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-win@2.1.1 (node_modules/7zip-bin-win):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-win@2.1.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ffi@2.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

full NPM debug log: https://gist.github.com/b9129f67b4ee62b89fbf7f201a2e1fb7

It seems to be an issue with `node-gyp` specifically w `node-gyp rebuild`

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was I had Python 3 installed @ `~/miniconda3` so even thought I was running the install script with Python 2.7 something else, I think electron, was referencing the Python on my path or something like that which was Python 3.

I `rm -rf ~/miniconda3` then `rm -rf node_modules` and its working.